# Javascript SFDC Custom Case Button- Want "new comment" window to render in parent window like Close Case (Salesforce custom button)

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I created a custom case escalation button (see below) executing javascript to:

1. Change case owner to a Queue
2. Change case status to Escalated
3. and allow support agent to add a comment before escalation and
   parent page reloads.

It works fine but support reps want the new comment page to render in the same parent page (same way the close case button works) and I just can't figure out the syntax or function to do this.

The way it is working now is it opens a new window for adding comment and then, after saving this child window closes and refreshes parent window with updated data.

Your help much appreciated!

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
parent.ID='{!Case.ParentId}'
caseObj.Status = 'Escalated';
caseObj.OwnerId = '00GE0000001ZsMH';
onclick='window.close()';
window.open('/00a/e?parent_id={!Case.Id}&retURL=/{!Case.Id}');
var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);

if (result[0].success=='false') {
     alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else {

     location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good way you can do that with just a Javascript button.  A better choice would be a little Visualforce page which allows the agent to enter the comment and sets the status and owner accordingly on save.